# Adding in an innerJoin a where clause on the many to many joinning table

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have an existing query with a join:

```
  public function findClientsAndTheirUsers($user_id, $search) {
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
      ->select('c.client_id, c.title, u.user_id, u.email')
      ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
      ->innerJoin('u.clients', 'c')
      ->innerJoin('c.users', 'cu')
      ->andWhere("cu.user_id = {$user_id}")
      ->groupBy('c.client_id')
      ->orderBy('c.title, u.email', 'ASC');
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
  }
```

resting on these tables:

`client`

```
| client_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | tinytext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

`user`

```
| user_id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email          | varchar(255)         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
```

`user_has_client`

```
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| client_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
```

with these entities:

`Client`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="clients")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_client",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")}
 * )
 */
protected $users;
```

`User`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Client", mappedBy="users")
 */
protected $clients;
```

`UserHasClient`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
protected $user_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
protected $client_id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userHasClients")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="userHasClients")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $client;
```

Now, I just added a `roles` column to the `user_has_client` table:

```
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| client_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| roles     | tinytext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

And I would like to update the query so that it returns only those users with, say, `admin` roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope it will be helpfull-

```
public function findClientsAndTheirUsers($user_id, $search)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c.client_id, c.title, u.user_id, u.email')
            ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->innerJoin('u.userHasClients', 'uhc')
            ->innerJoin('uhc.client', 'c')
            ->where("u.user_id = {$user_id}")
            ->andWhere("uhc.roles = :role")->setParameter('role', $role)
            ->groupBy('c.client_id')
            ->orderBy('c.title, u.email', 'ASC');
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

let me know if you still get problem.

Comment: I posted a more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (untested, DQL is not my strongest point):

```
public function findClientsAndTheirUsers($user_id, $search)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c.client_id, c.title, u.user_id, u.email')
            ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->innerJoin('u.userHasClients', 'uhc')
            ->innerJoin('uhc.client', 'c')
            ->andWhere("u.user_id = {$user_id}")
            ->andWhere("uhc.roles = {$role}")
            ->groupBy('c.client_id')
            ->orderBy('c.title, u.email', 'ASC');
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

You need the ManyToOne and OneToMany with UserHasClient entity in your DQL to get the roles.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gautam Rai's answer I could write the missing mapping in my User class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserHasClient", mappedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $userHasClients;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->userHasClients = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add UserHasClient entity to collection (one to many).
 *
 * @param \Application\Entity\UserHasClient $userHasClient
 * @return \Application\Entity\User
 */
public function addUserHasClient(UserHasClient $userHasClient)
{
  $this->userHasClients[] = $userHasClient;

  return $this;
}

/**
 * Get UserHasClient entity collection (one to many).
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getUserHasClients()
{
  return $this->userHasClients;
}
```

It was then possible to traverse the entities from the user to its role and client:

```
->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
->innerJoin('u.userHasClients', 'uhc')
->innerJoin('uhc.client', 'c')
->andWhere("uhc.roles like :role")
->setParameter('role', '%' . $role . '%')
```